# How to get all value from request.POST in intermediate pages of django admin action

Tags: django, django-admin

[image]

As shown above, after press Export button, only "Django 1" returns through the print() command.

Wondering hwo to get all three values from this kind of interactive?

```html
# admin.py
def export(self, request, queryset):
        if "apply" in request.POST:
            queryset.update(status="exported")
            title = request.POST['title']
            print(title, _selected_action)

            self.message_user(request,
                              "Changed status on {} orders".format(queryset.count()))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())

        context = admin.site.each_context(request)  
        context.update({
            'data': queryset
        })             
        return render(request, 'admin/export.html', context=context)
    export.short_description = "export"
```

```html
<!-- export.html -->
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for d in data %}
        <p>
            {{ d.pk }}.{{ d }}
            <input type="text" name="title" value={{ d.title }} size="50" autofocus />
        </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="_selected_action" value="{{ d.pk }}" />
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="export" />
    <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Export" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `request.POST.getlist('title')`

Comment: @DanielRoseman Tried, but it returns "'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'get_list'"

Comment: It's not `get_list`, but `getlist`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ouch, thx!

Answer (score 0):

As @DanielRoseman mentioned in the comment area, request.POST.getlist('title') works well here.